# - (void)applicationWillResignActive and save string -->ERROR

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, application-settings

I want to compare two strings after reloading my App.
(strold and strnew are declared global)

But if i call the string '*strold*' in **-applicationWillEnterForeground:** i get the following error message:

0x011eca62  <+0022>  push   %edi

0x011eca63  <+0023>  mov    0x8(%edx),%edi  (BAD EXIT FOR THIS LINE)

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application{

    opendate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    strnew = [formatter stringFromDate:opendate];
    NSLog(@"Active %@",strnew);
    NSLog(@"Inctive %@",strold);


}


- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application{

    closedate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    strold = [formatter stringFromDate:closedate];

}
```

I just want to check if a day changed actually.
significanttime Method did not worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to `retain` `strold` as it is `autorelease`d.

```
strold = [[formatter stringFromDate:closedate] retain];
```

or

```
self.strold = [formatter stringFromDate:closedate];
```

if `strold` is defined as a retained property.